# Cannot use 'cd' command in Python console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, cd

I want to change directory using 'cd' command in PyCharm's python console. It works all the time until I bought a new PC.

Environment is Python 3.7; Pycharm 2019.1.1.
I google it and some guys told me to use os.chdir() but I want to use 'cd' because it is easy to use.

The error report is:

```
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined
```

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are running PyCharm's console? The vanilla console would give you this exact error.

Comment: Here is the screenshot.

Comment: With PyCharm Professional 2018.2.3 the console offers commands like cd, pwd, run. In PyCharm Professional 2019.1.4 these functions are gone, maybe because some option is off by default. I cannot add an screenshot in a comment to show the behaviour in the old version so I tried an answer which was deleted. It clearly was not an answer but how can I put an image file into a comment to prove that, contrary to the answer below, the cd command really existed and worked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cd` is not a Python command. You can't use it unless you're running in a non-standard interpreter that provides access to it. Even if you could use it, running `cd` in a subshell (which is how most other interpreters expose shell commands) wouldn't change the working directory for the *Python* session you're in.

If you use an alternate interpreter/interpreter wrapper like `ipython`, yes, it has `cd` built-in the way you'd expect it to function.

But if you're on the bog standard Python interpreter, just use `os.chdir`. You can always alias it to something shorter if you like, e.g.

```
>>> from os import chdir as cd
>>> cd('foo/bar')
```

Comment: You can also `cd` to your desired directory before launching a python console, and then `os.listdir(".")` will be showing you the contents of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: An old installation with PyCharm Professional 2018.2.3 where commands like cd, pwd, run work - and a new computer with PyCharm Professional 2019.1.4 where these commands are not working any more as xxyao describes.
I asked the tech support at jetbrains and got the following answer which worked perfectly for me:

- Install the iPython package
- iPython must be enabled, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/console.html
  [image]

+1 for Antonina from jetbrains