# Can't run python program

Tags: python

Id be very happy to know how to run the program, i've found this command and want to know if its suitable or it can be done somehow else? :

```
python3 calculator.py
```

I tried putting this text :

```
# Prompt for user input
a = float(int(input("Enter the first number: 1")))
b = float(int(input("Enter the first number: 2")))

python3 calculator.py
```

Maybe you have some insights? (My python version is 3.12)

Comment: The first 3 lines should be inside the `calculator.py` file. The last line is what you type in the command prompt to execute the code.

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78142536/the-commands-doesnt-work-what-should-i-do

Comment: As @Barmar says. But note that the command line must be running from the folder containing calculator.py or Python will never find it. Also If you have no joy, and you are on Windows, you might try using: `py calculator.py` rather than `python3 calculator.py` (in case python3 has not been added to the PATH variable).

Comment: @lastchance same contributor about the same code, but a different question, I think.

Comment: @Lee-xp Thanks i moved first two lines to the actual file, also I tried to change path to the exact folder and then executing command but it still doesn't work..

Comment: @WUBBIS Please share the actual error messages that you're getting instead of just saying that "it doesn't work". Edit the error into your question instead of pasting them here as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the text labeled "I tried putting this text:" terminal input? If so then that is incorrect; it should be inside a file titled 'calculator.py', excluding line 5.

If the text is inside 'calculator.py' line 5 'python3 calculator.py' should not exist; instead it should be run on command line after navigating to 'calculator.py''s containing folder like so:

Windows:

```
cd C:\Path\To\File
python calculator.py
```

Linux:

```
cd /Path/To/File
python calculator.py
```

Comment: Yes of course cd the command is
C:\Calculator
 and the error code is
File "C:\Users\danie\PycharmProjects\ScienceLab\calculator.py", line 2
    cd C:\Calculator
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax          

also i found this article as i using pycharm maybe it somehow relates to my thing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859545/cannot-use-cd-command-in-python-console

Comment: Yeah that changes things a lot. Since you can't use the cd command in Pycharm, try using Windows 10's built-in command line (press windows key + r, type in "cmd" (no quotation marks)) and then try my command stuff above. Do you want to delete your first 5 comments and I do the same for mine? I swear my mouse wheel is breaking scrolling down all this way :P

Comment: Ahahah we can, i still not paid for consultation with you :D i tried that i got C:\Users\danie>cd C:\Calculator

C:\Calculator>             is it correct?

Comment: Yeah it should be correct. Just run the command "dir" (no quotation marks, run after the cd command) to make sure that calculator.py is in the folder. Then "python calculator.py" (again, no quotations) should run your program. If that doesn't work, I've got nothing else. :(

Comment: thanks it was file named calculator.py.txt thanks so much man!!

Comment: :D No problem! If everything's all done then marking a response as accepted will help other people see that you don't need more responses. All the best in your coding!

Answer (score 1):

So lets check that you are in the right folder first of all. To do this simply go to the command line (`Windows-R`, then press return). Then type:

```
dir
```

You should see `calculator.py` in the list of files. If it is not there, you are in the wrong directory.

Secondly use the command below to see what versions of Python are available to you:

```
py -0
```

This gives me:

[image]

You should see at least one version when you do it. The asterisk means that 3.12 is the currently active version.

If you have done both these things, then executing

```
py calculator.py
```

at the command line should cause the program to run. If not, try:

```
python calculator.py
```

If it that doesn't work, post a comment telling us what response you get.

Comment: Thanks man i resolved it, other person suggested using dir command and it was cruicial! the file name was .txt at the end. Although in python i cant use commands to run python and cd. Maybe if im wrong you can correct me, but i appreciate your support!:)