What is Python's built-in (?) cd() function?
When I open Python's console (Python 3.11.7 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:05:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]) I can use a command cd(). Without importing anything or doing anything.
For example when I type cd(aaaa), I will receive:
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '(aaaa)'

When I type help(cd), I receive:
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined

Which makes no sense, because using cd() just seconds before did something about finding a file one has to specify.
So what is cd()? In other answers I see that there's no built-in cd() function in python and one has to make one by themselves, but in my case it is already there without any imports.
So my questions are:

What is the cd() function?
If it's something very unusual, then how can I explore it further myself?


Like other OS functions it's in the os model: os.chdir(). help is correct -- there is no cd in Python; if IPython or something else you're using adds one, that's separate from Python itself (and since you didn't tell us you're using IPython, the question doesn't have enough details to be answerable).

this appears to be an ipython extension -- not the vanilla python prompt

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859545/cannot-use-cd-command-in-python-console

The linked question may not be clear. You are likely using ipython (not the regular python shell) and it has been extended with magic commands. Its not a python function and you shouldn't use parenthesis. You asked for a directory literally called (aaaa). Try cd aaaa.
